# Windows 7 partition D: to unallocated space?

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu, so I'm using Windows Disk Management to partition my D:

After using Shrink Volume, the result is 50GB of "free space" attached to the D:. From what I've read I need *unallocated space* to install Ubuntu. So how do I get 50GB of "unallocated space"?

[image: I want to install Ubuntu]

Comment: It's the same thing. They just call it different names. *This* free space is not allocated to a (logical) partition, so it is unallocated.

Comment: Are you sure? It's highlighted together with the D:. The legend box says there is an option for "Unallocated".

Comment: It is allocated to an extended partition (that's why the whole thing is green), but within the extended partition, one can make logical partitions - and that space is not allocated to logical partitions (hence unallocated). Ubuntu can and does work fine with extended partitions.

Comment: @muru: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from comments:

Your "free space" is allocated to an extended partition (that's why the whole thing is green), but *within the extended partition*, you can make *logical partitions* - and the free space space is currently not allocated to logical partitions (hence "unallocated").

Ubuntu can and does work fine with extended partitions...